# Labyrinth in python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to compare the length of the keys of a dictionary and then save the content of the longest in a variable.

I'm doing it so

```
def path_mas_largo (labyrinth, idlaberinto):
    for i in range (len (labyrinth [idlaberinto]) - 1):
        if len (labyrinth [idlaberinto] [i] ['ensenanza' + str (i)]) > len (labyrinth [idlaberinto] [i + 1] ['ensenanza' + str (i + 1)]):
            j = len (labyrinth [idlaberinto] [i] ['ensenanza' + str (i)])
            if j > len (labyrinth [idlaberinto] [i + 1] ['ensenanza' + str (i + 1)]):
               camino_largo = laberinto [idlaberinto] [i] ['ensenanza' + str (i)]
               print (long_path)
               emular_recorrido (camino_largo, ventana, blanco, negro, celeste, aumento)
```

The problem is that more than one value is stored in the variable
How could we solve it?

Comment: Can you show an example about how your dictionary keys and values look like?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: compare the length of the keys of a dictionary ... the longest in a variable.

I assume, you are using `str` keys

```
# Creat a dict with keys from a sentence
_dict = dict.fromkeys("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.".split(), None)

# Create a ordered list from the dict keys
_list = list(_dict.keys())

# Use the buildin index/max function to get the index of the max value
_max = _list.index(max(_list))

print("_list:{}\nmax:[{}] {}".format(_list, _max, _list[_max]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> _list:['of', 'the', 'simply', 'Lorem', 'is', 'and', 'typesetting', 'industry.', 'Ipsum', 'dummy', 'printing', 'text']
> max:[6] typesetting
> ```

---

If don't want to use the building functions:

```
# Init start values
_max_key = None
_max = 0

# Loop the dict keys
for key in _dict.keys():

    # Get the length of this key
    _len = len(key)

    # Condition: If this key length is greater than the previous
    if _len > _max:

        # Set _max to the current _len, for next Condition
        _max = _len

        # Save the key value
        _max_key = key

print("max_key: {}".format(_max_key))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> max_key: typesetting
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***